# How to calculate the session change of daily bars

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that looks like:

| date | volume | open | close | high | low | previous close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-02 | 1756159.0 | 118.38 | 119.57 | 120.34 | 116.49 |  |
| 2022-05-03 | 3217838.0 | 119.72 | 122.4 | 123.98 | 119.09 | 119.57 |
| 2022-05-04 | 2460350.0 | 121.69 | 126.3 | 126.69 | 121.44 | 122.4 |
| 2022-05-05 | 2123645.0 | 124.62 | 122.15 | 125.21 | 120.8 | 126.3 |
| 2022-05-06 | 1629034.0 | 120.88 | 121.08 | 121.88 | 118.0 | 122.15 |
| 2022-05-09 | 1861704.0 | 119.13 | 113.11 | 119.13 | 112.64 | 121.08 |
| 2022-05-10 | 2141753.0 | 115.44 | 116.64 | 117.94 | 113.14 | 113.11 |
| 2022-05-11 | 1607013.0 | 115.7 | 113.99 | 118.0 | 113.84 | 116.64 |
| 2022-05-12 | 1338023.0 | 113.61 | 116.13 | 116.25 | 112.78 | 113.99 |
| 2022-05-13 | 1328411.0 | 117.38 | 119.38 | 120.715 | 117.27 | 116.13 |

I am trying to create a column which finds the difference between the previous close and the open:

```
def get_change(current, previous):
    print(current, 'current')
    print(previous, 'previous')
    if current == previous:
        return 0
    try:
        return (abs(current - previous) / previous) * 100.0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return float('inf')

final_df['change'] = get_change(df['o'], final_df['previous close'])
```

Like so (where 2 is the difference between previous close and open):

| date | volume | open | close | high | low | previous close | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-02 | 1756159.0 | 118.38 | 119.57 | 120.34 | 116.49 |  | 2 |
| 2022-05-03 | 3217838.0 | 119.72 | 122.4 | 123.98 | 119.09 | 119.57 | 2 |
| 2022-05-04 | 2460350.0 | 121.69 | 126.3 | 126.69 | 121.44 | 122.4 | 2 |
| 2022-05-05 | 2123645.0 | 124.62 | 122.15 | 125.21 | 120.8 | 126.3 | 2 |
| 2022-05-06 | 1629034.0 | 120.88 | 121.08 | 121.88 | 118.0 | 122.15 | 2 |
| 2022-05-09 | 1861704.0 | 119.13 | 113.11 | 119.13 | 112.64 | 121.08 | 2 |
| 2022-05-10 | 2141753.0 | 115.44 | 116.64 | 117.94 | 113.14 | 113.11 | 2 |
| 2022-05-11 | 1607013.0 | 115.7 | 113.99 | 118.0 | 113.84 | 116.64 | 2 |
| 2022-05-12 | 1338023.0 | 113.61 | 116.13 | 116.25 | 112.78 | 113.99 | 2 |
| 2022-05-13 | 1328411.0 | 117.38 | 119.38 | 120.715 | 117.27 | 116.13 | 2 |

How do I get the change value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IUUC, you can do

```py
df['change'] = df['open'].sub(df['previous close']).abs().div(df['previous close']).mul(100.0)
```

```
print(df)

         date     volume    open   close     high     low  previous close    change
0  2022-05-02  1756159.0  118.38  119.57  120.340  116.49             NaN       NaN
1  2022-05-03  3217838.0  119.72  122.40  123.980  119.09          119.57  0.125450
2  2022-05-04  2460350.0  121.69  126.30  126.690  121.44          122.40  0.580065
3  2022-05-05  2123645.0  124.62  122.15  125.210  120.80          126.30  1.330166
4  2022-05-06  1629034.0  120.88  121.08  121.880  118.00          122.15  1.039705
5  2022-05-09  1861704.0  119.13  113.11  119.130  112.64          121.08  1.610505
6  2022-05-10  2141753.0  115.44  116.64  117.940  113.14          113.11  2.059942
7  2022-05-11  1607013.0  115.70  113.99  118.000  113.84          116.64  0.805898
8  2022-05-12  1338023.0  113.61  116.13  116.250  112.78          113.99  0.333363
9  2022-05-13  1328411.0  117.38  119.38  120.715  117.27          116.13  1.076380
```

Comment: Thanks again will accept in 5 minutes, have a great weekend !